# A pyramid $ABCDS$ in which all edges have different lengths and $|AS|+|CS|=|BS|+|DS|$

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to solve the following problem from the Polish *XI Olimpiada Matematyczna Gimnazjalistów* (question 7 from [this document](http://www.omg.edu.pl/uploads/attachments/1etap15.pdf). The submission deadline of 12 October 2015 has passed.

[image]

I drew the grids below in order to clarify and notice some dependencies, but I cannot find any.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Excuse my bad handwriting]

I build a space rectangular coordinate to solve your question, but the picture has bad quality.

Comment: Thank you, it's a very good analitycal approach. Could you please provide a way to solve the equation? In other words - how did you find the solution for this equation: $|AS|+|CS|=|BS|+|DS|$?

Comment: To be honest, I use wolframalpha to do it to make the calculation is correct. If you just want to prove your question, it's easy to find one solution, for example , you can observe how to make$|AS|=|DS|$(there is no need to discuss $z$, so take $y=0$ and $x=1/2$ and  check if this qualify $|BS|=|CS|$). If you want to a complete solution, you have to do the calculation, because there are infinite solutions here.